# Set GUI as default on CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos

I have just installed CentOS.  When it boots, it does so to the command line UI. I'd prefer the GUI. I found these steps to switch the GUI by default:

https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-start-gui-in-centos-7-linux/

However, when I follow those steps, I don't get the same results as the tutorial. When I enter the command to set the GUI as the default, I am told:

> Failed to set default target: Interactive authentication required

[image]

Comment: That tutorial shows those commands being run from the `root` user. Try running these commands as `root` or with `sudo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`systemctl isolate graphical.target` should have started the graphical interface.

Have you installed a desktop environment (GNOME, KDE, XFCE, etc)?

The second command needs root(#) or sudo:

`sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target`

Comment: I had to install the GUI using this command: `yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop" –y`.  The process that followed  (to download the GUI) took hours. But once done, `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target` did the trick.  Thanks.